# Am I onto something regarding hidden rhombus-like structures hiding within N-dimensional honeycombs?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, tiling

*Hexagons* are made of 6 embedded rhombuses. The Rhombic dodecahedron
Has twice the number of rhombuses as the hexagon has yet those rhombuses are its exterior boundary. The exterior boundary of a hexagon is a flat line.

So, might there be an expansion sequence for these hidden-rhombus-like geometries and their resultant honeycomb-composite-forms, to arbitrary dimensions?
[image: this image uses colors to illustrate the 6 hidden congruent rhombuses inside of a hexagon as well as showing the rhomboid faces of a rhombic dodecahedron]

I have a practical motivation to find this hypothetical sequence as it could aid in the creation of cellular/rasterized plots and figures or models which do not suffer from the disproportionate distances of cube and square based raster cells.

Comment: In what sense is a hexagon made of 6 rhombuses?

Comment: @Karl in the sense that I outlined them in colors and you can see them there. 3 intersecting rhombuses making a star, and if you map that star so that the 6 outer tips meet at a singular point, then it creates 3 more smaller ones. It's in the picture. Are you blind and using tts to read this? Cos that's how I'll feel responsible for the miscommunication. It's there. I highlighted them broh.

Comment: @Karl perhaps I was overzealous with my colors and should've simply colored only 1 rhombus. Go to the colorful hexagon part of the image (click to expand if you must) (it's on the bottom edge) and focus on 1 color, Red, for example. Trace the Red. It is one rhombus. All the colors belong to 1 rhombus in that diagram example of what I saw.

Comment: By "made of" do you actually mean "contain"? Your rhombuses both overlap, and their union is a star of David, not a hexagon, so I don't really see how it is reasonable to say the hexagon is *made* of them.

Comment: If you can access it (personaly I can't) : "Multidimensional Honeycomb-like DNA Nanostructures Made of C-Motifs"
Anshula Tandon, Byeonghoon Kim, et al. ACS Biomater. Sci. Eng. 2023, 9, 2, 608–616